# Need help to find id of a specific element (external) to override styling by CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to modify (by CSS) the dark gray "Contact Us" button that's at the bottom right side of the following site: [coloraddicted.com](https://www.coloraddicted.com).

This is a button created by an external app, so the code is inaccessible. I only have the following (external) page to refer to for the possibility of finding the right id: https://icf.improvely.com/icf-button.js?v=1479350309&shop=coloraddicted-com.myshopify.com

> How can I find the "id" of the specific element in order to apply the
>   "overriding" CSS to it?

BTW, I have already tried several versions of the id's I see on the above mentioned external page but still haven't found the right one.

I can't remember all of them, but some I have already tried are:

```
#icf_button
#icf.click_button
#icf_contact_form button {
#icf_contact_form add_button {
```

Answer (score 1):

Style `Contact button` by css has no effect, because right after user hover, `js` code excuted & override on.

You can put `js` code at the end of the body, to re-override on the library code (not the good way, but have to), example

```
let contactButton = document.querySelector('#shop-colorful-products-printed-on-demand-just-for-you > div:nth-child(38)');
contactButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

Demo image https://tinker.press/images/change-style-by-js-to-override-2017-01-17_090946.png

Comment: @shipshape, Michael Coker & Anh Le Hoang: First of all thank you all for your help and I apologize for taking about 4 days to reply. I tried your suggestions but it seems that the .js file overrides them. The code works when I add it to the page through "Inspect" on Google Chrome (right before the closing </body> tag) but it doesn't work when I add it to my actual page. Unless anybody else has an idea of how I can prevent that, I think I will have to live with the situation .... Thank you, again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the button.js script you linked to, I don't think you can target this (reliably) in CSS. They style everything with that button using inline styles and just append it to `body`.

You could *potentially* use `:nth-of-type` (like `https://icf.improvely.com/icf-button.js?v=1479350309&shop=coloraddicted-com.myshopify.com`) but that would be super unreliable as I'm assuming you have a bunch of scripts and stuff on the site that dynamically append to the page, creating a variable number of divs as direct descendants of body. FWIW, `nth-of-type(13)` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The element doesn't have an id, so you can't select it that way. But the site appears to be using jQuery, so you could try using [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to target the element based on its contents:

```
$( "div:contains('Contact Us')" ).css( "font-size", "2em" );
```

But that would target any div containing the text "Contact Us". You can use :filter to select divs that contain *only* the text "Contact Us":

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Contact Us";
}).css("font-size", "2em");
```

You could use jQuery to either apply CSS directly, or to give the element an id. This solution is kind of kludgy, but might work in a pinch.